# Uso de scripts e bootstrap externo

Tags: angular

Boa noite pessoal estou tentando implementar um script e css externo no meu projeto angular, e vi que era apenas preciso jogar ele dentro da pasta angular e usar um tag de link como essa abaixo para usar:

```
<script src="assets/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Isso procede, pois o Angular não consegue encontrar o arquivo na assets e não carrega o evento do script.

Como poderia usar de outra forma, sem recorrer a pasta node_modules para usar??

Comment: considere editar sua pergunta e adicionar a parte do código em questão ... só assim para alguém tentar reproduzir e encontrar o erro e a possível solução

Comment: edite a pergunta está sem código, teste colocar depois </head>

Answer (score 0):

Em projetos angular normalmente para você incluir arquivos de estilo e javascript voce precisa incluir o caminho do script em um arquivo chamado angular-cli.json

algo como isso:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
```